# Document members for inherited classes in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using Sphinx's autodoc module for Python documentation. I want my inherited classes to show details of its member functions as well as its docstrings. So I set the following option:

`export SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS=members,undoc-members,show-inheritance,inherited-members`

Although doing this successfully edits the rst files with desired labels, it does not get the job done. My html page shows a hyperlink to the inherited class documentation. I want it elaborated instead.

I have also used the `autodoc_default_flags` in conf.py which somehow does not seem to work:

`autodoc_default_flags = ['members', 'undoc-members', 'show-inheritance', 'inherited-members']`

Am I doing it right? Does the order of the `SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS` matter and am I giving the right order? Also, is there an option under `sphinx-apidoc` or `sphinx-build` commands to do the same thing?